# I need a tool that can organize my time and manage my tasks

Tags: macos, time-management

Ok so I am really swamped at work, and need a tool that keep tracks of what I did and what I didn't. I need the tool to do the following:

1. I need that tool to set priorities on my tasks.
2. Some tasks do have subtasks inside of it, so I need to keep track of those as well.
3. Pending status, some tasks may require that I need to wait for other parties to finish their work.
4. Intuitive and easy to use.
5. Run on Mac OS X

Answer (score 1):

Try [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/)

It might seem a bit silly but it fits your requirements more or less exactly as you have described them. Shallow learning curve too.